# merge multiple fields into one and keep data

Tags: merge, microsoft-access-2007

ok, tricky one:

i need to merge one field in an access 2007 database and merge it into one filed in a query. hard part: i need to keep the data that goes with the new records.

example:

```
col1 |col2 |col3 |data1 |data2 |
1    |     |8    |90    |true  |
     |     |     |40    |false |
2    |     |     |90    |true  |
8    |4    |10   |100   |false |
```

output

```
out|data1|data2|
1  |90   |true |
8  |90   |true |
2  |40   |true |
8  |100  |false|
4  |100  |false|
10 |100  |false|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create three separate but very similar append queries.   With criteria in col1, col2 or col3 being "not is null".

Comment: i have 7 fields like the col fields... is there any way to make this faster to do?

Comment: Yes, if you were generating the queries in VBA code but otherwise no. Besides once you have the first query done the subsequent queries should only take a few seconds to copy and change